# Can't access content of page when attempting to add Dom to chrome-extension:// URL

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension spawns a temp .html page. I want to manipulate the DOM of the sample.html page that was created, but can't. I can manipulate the DOM for any other page without issue. The problem seems to be with the fact my temp .html page resides within chrome-extension://

**Error Message:**
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://123/sample.html?id=100". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

**Note:** for simplicity sake I provided sample code that exhibits the same Error. Once loaded I can use the key combo to inject a div and some text into any webpage (Mac-> Cmd+Shift+P or PC Ctrl+Shift+P)

I've tried adding all possible permissions and even web_accessible_resources to the manifest.json. (I don't believe this to be the issue). I've tried different ways to inject the code into the sample.html by calling out the specific tabId, activeTab or even setting the tabId to null within the background file. I've read through stackoverflow, googled and looked around but came up short.

manifest.json

```
   {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "sample1",
    "description": "sample1",
    "version": "0.0.1",

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_title": "sample"
    },
    "commands":
    {
        "saveImageCommand":
        {
            "suggested_key":
            {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Z",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+Z"
            },
            "description": "Toggle Save Image"
        },
        "playback":
        {
            "suggested_key":
            {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+P",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+P"
            },
            "description": "load player Image"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "*://*/*"


    ],

    "background":
    {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
    ,
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "chrome-extension://*/sample.html?id=*"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if (command === 'saveImageCommand') {
        capturecurrent();
    }
    if (command === 'playback') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'var divNode = document.createElement("div");divNode.setAttribute("id", "video1Div");var instructions = document.createTextNode("testing");divNode.appendChild(instructions);document.body.appendChild(divNode)'
        });
    }

});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(screenshotUrl) {
        var viewTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('sample.html')
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: viewTabUrl });
    });
});
```

sample.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="firstDiv">firstDiv</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Expected Results:**
For me to interact directly with the DOM on the temp sample.html page.

**Note:**
I don't want to build out buttons for DOM manipulation directly within the sample.html page. That defeats the purpose of this exercise. Esp since I want to use shortcut key combos to call this DOM manipulation (Mac-> Cmd+Shift+P or PC Ctrl+Shift+P)

**Actual Results:**
I am able to interact with the DOM on any normal website using the shortcut key combo but not the sample.html that URL starts with chrome-extension://

Comment: You can't inject content scripts into your own chrome-extension:// page and you don't need to. Those are only to augment web pages. You can access your extension's page page either directly via chrome.extension.getViews or by sending messages to its script (loaded in its html's script tag) using chrome.tabs.sendMessage, for example. BTW no need for chrome.extension.getURL in the background script.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm. Using sendMessage resolved my issue.